# Is there a way to setup oAuth with Openvpn or wireguard?

Tags: vpn, single-sign-on, oauth, token

I'm looking to build a set of services that require a single sign on. Basically, you login to my oAuth provider, and you have access to an openvpn connection(or wireguard) and a website, without additional security needed, with the possible exception of an original setup.

My question therefore is: How do I automate openVpn so that I can do either one of two things:

1. Authenticate my connection with a token instead of a password/username

Or

2. Authenticate my connection with a username/password, that I can then send to my oAuth provider and return a token to the client, for other applications

Answer (score 2):

Read [man openvpn](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/). It is the definitive source of information about OpenVPN.

Let me just copy-paste a part of that page. I think this should completely answer your question:

> `--auth-token` token
>
> This is not an option to be used directly in any
>   configuration files, but rather push this option from a
>   `--client-connect` script or a `--plugin` which hooks into the
>   `OPENVPN_PLUGIN_CLIENT_CONNECT` or `OPENVPN_PLUGIN_CLIENT_CONNECT_V2`
>   calls. This option provides a possibility to replace the clients
>   password with an authentication token during the lifetime of the
>   OpenVPN client.
>
> Whenever the connection is renegotiated and the `--auth-user-pass-verify` 
>   script or `--plugin` making use of the
>   `OPENVPN_PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY` hook is triggered, it will pass over
>   this token as the password instead of the password the user provided. The
>   authentication token can only be reset by a full reconnect where the server
>   can push new options to the client. The password the user entered is never
>   preserved once an authentication token have been set. If the OpenVPN server
>   side rejects the authentication token, the client will receive an
>   `AUTH_FAIL` and disconnect.
>
> The purpose of this is to enable two factor authentication methods, such as
>   HOTP or TOTP, to be used without needing to retrieve a new OTP code each
>   time the connection is renegotiated. Another use case is to cache
>   authentication data on the client without needing to have the users
>   password cached in memory during the life time of the session.
>
> To make use of this feature, the `--client-connect` script or `--plugin`
>   needs to put
>
> `push "auth-token UNIQUE_TOKEN_VALUE"`
>
> into the file/buffer for dynamic configuration data. This will then make
>   the OpenVPN server to push this value to the client, which replaces the
>   local password with the `UNIQUE_TOKEN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across a few references while I was searching for a similar Single Sign On requirement for WireGuard. I am listing them down below.

- https://github.com/subspacecloud/subspace
- https://pritunl.com/ (Has support for both WireGuard and OpenVPN)

Answer (score 2):

Depends which provider you are using, but there's an open-source WireGuard VPN (https://github.com/firezone/firezone) that supports any SSO provider with an OIDC connector.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).